# Missing required parameters for [Route: complaintsinput] [URI: complaints-input/{id}/{pres_id}] - Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

**I redirect route from controller function like this:**

```
return redirect()->route('complaintsinput', [
            'id' => $patient_id,
            'pres_id' => $prescriptionID
        ]);
```

OR

```
return redirect(route('complaintsinput', ['id' => $patient_id, 'pres_id' => $prescriptionID]));
```

**$patient_id** and **$prescriptionID** get the right value.

**This is my web.php :**

```
Route::get('complaints-input/{id}/{pres_id}', [PrescriptionController::class, 'complaintsInput'])->name('complaintsinput');
```

**This is controller function:**

```
public function complaintsInput($id, $pres_id){
        $patient_info = ConfirmAppointment::Where("patient_id", "=", $id)->first();
        return view('prescription.chief_complaints', compact('patient_info', 'pres_id'));

    }
```

This is the URL (get parameter value correctly):

```
http://localhost:8000/complaints-input/72/72067183
```

But don't know why give this error !!

Comment: Welcome to SO... usally this error occure from blade file check in your blade file

Comment: My blade file is absolutely OK, is there another cause for this error ??

Comment: when this error occur after submit form or specific url ?

Answer (score 2):

Last time I received this error it was due to the way I was generating the URL in my blade file. How are you generating the URL?

It should be something like:

```
{{ route('complaintsinput', ['id' => $patient_id, 'pres_id' => $prescriptionID]) }}
```

I also had this issue with the web file and had to change mine to have a "?" in the web route:

```
Route::get('complaints-input/{id?}/{pres_id?}', [PrescriptionController::class, 'complaintsInput'])->name('complaintsinput');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
return redirect('complaints-input/'.$patient_id.'/'.$prescriptionID);
```